# Automapper: Ignore types in a collection that have not been set up

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Consider the following scenario:

```
    public class DestinationType1 { }

    public class DestinationType2 { }

    public class SourceType { }

    public class SourceTypeA : SourceType { }

    public class SourceTypeB : SourceType { }
```

I set up these mappings:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType2>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceTypeB, DestinationType2>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType1>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceTypeA, DestinationType1>();
```

Then try to map the following:

```
        var sourceTypes = new List<SourceType>{new SourceTypeA(), new SourceTypeB()};
        var destinationType1s = Mapper.Map<List<DestinationType2>>(sourceTypes);
        var destinationType2s = Mapper.Map<List<DestinationType1>>(sourceTypes);
```

What i want to achieve is for destinationType1s to only have one member, mapped from the SourceTypeA in the source list, and destinationType2s to only have one mapped from SourceTypeB. However what i get is two elements in both lists mapped from both the source types.

Is this achievable somehow out of the box or do i need to write my own value resolver or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `OfType` LINQ extension method to filter the `sourceTypes` list.

```
var sourceTypes = new List<SourceType>{new SourceTypeA(), new SourceTypeB()};
var destinationType1s = Mapper.Map<List<DestinationType1>>(sourceTypes.OfType<SourceTypeA>());
var destinationType2s = Mapper.Map<List<DestinationType2>>(sourceTypes.OfType<SourceTypeB>());
```

`OfType<type>` will produce an `IEnumerable<type>` so you could also remove the 2 maps for the base `SourceType` if you're not going to use them.

If you want to filter for more than one type, then you could create your own extension method similar to `OfType` that takes a list of types or takes the DestinationType and looks up which types are mapped to it. Here's something that works using `Mapper.FindTypeMapFor` to filter only compatible types:

```
//Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType2>(); -- don't want this!

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceTypeB, DestinationType2>();

//Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType1>(); -- don't want this!

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceTypeA, DestinationType1>();

var sourceTypes = new List<SourceType> { new SourceTypeA(), new SourceTypeB() };
var destinationType1s = Mapper.Map<List<DestinationType1>>(sourceTypes.CompatibleMappedTypes<DestinationType1>());
var destinationType2s = Mapper.Map<List<DestinationType2>>(sourceTypes.CompatibleMappedTypes<DestinationType2>());
```

...

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable CompatibleMappedTypes<TDestination>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        foreach (var s in source)
        {
            if (Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(s.GetType(), typeof(TDestination)) != null) yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That definately is a solution, however the "real" situation i have involves more source and destination objects so i would like say one list to have A, B and C types mapped to it, and the other D, E, and F, so then i would have to create another base class that A, B and C inherit from and same for D, E, F i suppose. Would be nice if you could specify somehow that automapper should skip any class it doesn't have an explicit map for.

Comment: Well, you've given it a mapping for the base class, so it does have an explicit map for everything in your list.

Comment: You are right ofcourse, and I do understand why I get both elements in the mapped list and your solution is probably what I will have to do. But it would have been useful if there was a way to tell automapper to only map the derived types that had a mapping set up for that specific class.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer. Should give you what you're looking for.